# Set up an xcode bot to build and deploy a nodejs express server

Tags: node.js, xcode, continuous-deployment, xcode-bots

I am attempting to set up a xcode project and bot that will build a nodejs application `on commit` from a github repository and restart the server after the build completes. The bot is currently picking up on the repository changes but fails to build correctly.

I am using a xcode `external build tool project` that uses `/bin/bash` as the tool path and the working directory is set to the local repository path.

The bot's `after integration` script is something like,

```
npm install --production
npm run build
npm run server:restart
```

I am getting errors like `[npm|node] is not recognized`.

Just looking for some clarity to what I might be missing or what could be going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to the beginning of your script and review the output:

```
which node
set | grep PATH
```

This will happen if node is not in your path, which may happen because build scripts have a pretty basic environment - they're not running as a normal user. You may need to add it to your PATH at the start of your build script.

Comment: `PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`
`/var/folders/0d/yd64rp1d7ydg45jq0ws9w_p0000087/T/CE82881A-F94A-47D1-B408-B6110B07DF00-33111-000356C5B7C745B6: line 8: npm: command not found`


I as added the `npm install` command after your suggested code

Comment: Run the same `which npm` command as a normal user on the box to determine where it's installed. For me, it's in `/usr/local/bin/npm` and if yours is the same, the PATH above won't find it.

If this is true for you as well, an `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin` as the first line of your script will fix it.

Comment: Add `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin` as the first line of the script helped me.